# Sql - exclude the 0 value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I execute this query

```
SELECT Kd_penyakit, Penyakit,
COUNT(case when Kd_gejala in ('G01','','G03','G04','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')then 1 else null end) / COUNT(kd_penyakit)*100 AS cases
FROM tbl_casebase 
GROUP BY Kd_penyakit 
ORDER BY cases DESC
```

and the result is like this

```
Kd_penyakit   Penyakit         cases

P01           Tipus Ayam       42.8571
P06           Produksi Telur   25.0000
P03           Salesma Ayam     14.2857
P02           Berak Darah      0.0000
P04           Gumboro          0.0000
P05           Mareks           0.0000
```

my question is how to exclude the 0 values so the result just like this

```
Kd_penyakit   Penyakit         cases

P01           Tipus Ayam       42.8571
P06           Produksi Telur   25.0000
P03           Salesma Ayam     14.2857
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out the unwanted rows before the aggregations, using `exists`:

```
SELECT Kd_penyakit, Penyakit,
COUNT(case when Kd_gejala in ('G01','G03','G04','') then 1 end) / COUNT(kd_penyakit)*100 AS cases
FROM tbl_casebase 
where exists (
   select 1 from tbl_casebase t2
   where tbl_casebase.Kd_penyakit = t2.Kd_penyakit
   and t2.Kd_gejala in ('G01','G03','G04','')
   )
GROUP BY Kd_penyakit
ORDER BY cases DESC
;
```

Note, you can omit "else null" when using a case expression with `count()`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to filter it in `HAVING` clause by using the same expression

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING COUNT(case when Kd_gejala in ('G01','','G03','G04','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')then 1 else null end) / COUNT(kd_penyakit)*100 > 0
ORDER BY ...
```

Since you're using mysql, it can be simply written using the `ALIAS` although it is not a standard practice and only working in mysql and when [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY extension](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is disaled.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING cases > 0
ORDER BY ...
```

- [Why does MySQL allow HAVING to use SELECT aliases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases)